# Is it possible to create a Windows Store App logo using XAML?

Tags: graphics, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, scaling, graphical-logo

I need to create logos for my Windows Store Apps. I am not a skilled graphic artist (pretty clueless as to the use of those tools, or even what they are).

I have the design in mind for what I want my logo to basically look like:

[image]

I could create this in XAML, using a grid, and placing images in various cells, using either Segoe UI Symbols characters and/or "commons" graphic images (of a camera and footprints), and then add the text in the great middle of it all. But how to then convert that image to the needed 50X50 pixels* for the app's logo? Wouldn't the images, and even the font characters, get too "smushed," for lack of a better term?

- Windows Store Apps actually require several different files at various scales and even width:height ratios, but Microsoft has made a tool available that can take a 50x50 logo and automatically generate all the other files.

So: Is it possible to create a Windows Store Apps logo using XAML, and if so, how? Otherwise, what is the preferred method/standard approach to this?

### UPDATE

With a little help from my friends (a "virtual one" found here, and an old hiking buddy), I was able to come up with one that I like. Logo:

[image]

...and splash screen:

[image]

Comment: They want a flattened raster image, if you'd like to throw an email up or something up long enough for me to grab it and I'll help you out real quick after work (I'm in CST time zone), since this isn't really programming related your question will probably get closed soon.

Comment: Sure, thanks: bclayshannon@att.net

Comment: RenderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn298556.aspx